# Apache Spark Native Libraries

Tags: hadoop, 64-bit, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I was recently able to build Apache Hadoop 2.5.1 with native 64 bit support. So,  I got rid of the annoying Native Libraries Warning.

I'm trying to configure Apache Spark. When I start spark-shell, the same warning appears:

```
14/09/14 18:48:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Some tips:

I had to download a pre-built 2.4 version of Spark because there is still no profile for Hadoop 2.5 with Maven.

The following exports were added to spark-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop-2.5.1/etc/hadoop

export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/hadoop-2.5.1/lib/native
```

Didn't work with spark-shell and spark-submit. My Hadoop local installation is configured as pseudo-distributed (ResourceManager + YARN support).

Answer (score 2):

You should add `HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
```