# Native library lz4 not available for Spark

Tags: macos, apache-spark

How do I add the `lz4` native libraries for use by Spark workers?

I have tried to add them via both  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and ( as shown - but no accepted or even upvoted answer - in [Apache Spark Native Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835715/apache-spark-native-libraries) ) - in `SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH`.  They are not working: we get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native lz4 library not available
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec.getCompressorType(Lz4Codec.java:125)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:165)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1201)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1094)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$BlockCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1444)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:277)
  at BIDMat.HDFSIO.writeThing(HDFSIO.scala:96)
```

Here is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/lz4/r131/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/lib:
12:15:35/BIDMach_Spark $ll /usr/local/Cellar/lz4/r131/lib
```

and the contents of the `lz4` related entry:

```
$ll /usr/local/Cellar/lz4/r131/lib
total 528
-r--r--r--  1 macuser  admin  71144 Sep 21  2015 liblz4.a
drwxr-xr-x  7 macuser  admin    238 Sep 21  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 macuser  admin    102 Jun 13 10:41 pkgconfig
-r--r--r--  1 macuser  admin  64120 Jun 13 10:41 liblz4.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 macuser  admin  64120 Jun 13 10:41 liblz4.1.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 macuser  admin  64120 Jun 13 10:41 liblz4.1.7.1.dylib
```

Comment: So I don't use OSX but you have no `.so` (`.bundle`?) files which is pretty much what you need here.

Comment: @zero323  Good question - I did not know the answer myself. Apparently .dylib is the mac equiv.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx

Comment: You need the `MH_BUNDLE` not `MH_DYLIB` (now I am smart ;) )

Comment: @zero323  This is well deeper than where I have gone so far. I simply installed the `lz4` via `brew` - and am attempting to use those results. If they (apparently) used MH_DYLIB on their gc++ options that is outside of my "reach".   Maybe I have to figure out how to compile native hadoop libraries on the mac. Sounding ominous.

Comment: Don't ask me. While it is good UNIX all these brews and stuff sound like a black magic ;) Still, I am fairly certain this is the issue. On a side note I answered the other question but it won't be useful here because the warning is about `libhadoop`.

Comment: @zero323 And I upvoted your answer over there.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't you just adjust the recipe to generate shared libraries?

Comment: @zero323  I went closer to the source and downloaded `lz4` source code. Unfortunately their `Makefile` only has `-shared` and not `-dynamiclib` in it: still working through how to translate that to `-module`.   This is bit more adventurous than I would prefer.

Comment: At the first glance `make lib` / `make install` should give you all you need.

Comment: That will just get us the same ol' .dynlib outputs.  I am looking into full blown native hadoop build now.

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to use lz4 on mac ?

Comment: @user401445 No I did not.

Comment: Note that spark is a parallel processing framework, designed with servers in mind. There are many linux servers, some windows servers, but not many Mac servers. So thought it is not impossible to do most things on Mac OS. It may be simpler to work on (a vm of) a different OS.

Answer (score -2):

Update your hadoop jars and should work perfectly fine.